# Drupal - Page PHP prints images OK unless on admin / some user pages

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

Here is the code ive been using in my page.tpl.php:

```
<div id="beforefooter">
<?php print l('<img src="imagesmy/logo.jpg" />', '<front>', array('html' => TRUE)); ?>
</div>

<div id="afterfooter">
    <a href="http://www.site.com" target="_blank" >
        <img src="imagesmy/credit.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

For most pages this works fine, but when on an admin page the images dont show up. Also on certain user pages (that you need to be registered to see) the images also dont show up.

From looking at the source code on the page it seems identical when it does and doesnt work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `base_path()` or `$base_path`

`print l('<img src="' . base_path() . 'imagesmy/logo.jpg" />', '<front>', array('html' => TRUE));`

Are the paths to the image exactly the same on the different pages? I saw a similar problem where it was trying to find the image at "www.example.com/admin/imagesmy/logo.jpg instead of in the document root

Comment: How can I get the second link in div#afterfooter working? Ive tried adapting your code from the first but I must have done something wrong. Thanks

Comment: `print l('<img src="' . base_path() . 'imagesmy/credit.jpg" />', 'http://www.site.com', array('html' => TRUE));` should work

Comment: Working with: <img src="<?php print $base_path ?>/imagesmy/credit.jpg" />

Comment: Yea those are sometimes picky.  There is also `$base_url` available as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try constructing your image using `drupal_get_path()` and it would be sure to resolve to the correct location for the image.

```
$img_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'name-of-your-theme') . '/images/logo.png';
$img = theme('image', $img_path, 'the-alt-text', 'the-title-text');
print l( $img, '<front>', array('html' => TRUE));
```